# How to extract part of a string with slash constraints?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

Hello I have some strings named like this:

`BURGERDAY / PPA / This is a burger fest`

I've tried using regex to get it but I can't seem to get it right.

The output should just get the final string of `This is a burger fest` (without the first whitespace)

Comment: `\/[^\/]+\/\s*(.*)`

Comment: I don't know why other have voted down, but this is a good place to start: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is there ever a slash in the target content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, we can capture our desired output after we reach to the last slash followed by any number of spaces:

```
.+\/\s+(.+)
```

where `(.+)` collects what we wish to return.

```js
const regex = /.+\/\s+(.+)/gm;
const str = `BURGERDAY / PPA / This is a burger fest`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/E8RhLO/1/)

#### Advices

Based on [revo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020526/revo)'s advice, we can also use this expression, which is much better:

```
\/ +([^\/]*)$
```

---

According to [Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian)'s advice, it may not be required to escape the forward slash, based on the language we wish to use and this would work for JavaScript:

```
.+/\s+(.+)
```

Also, we assume in target content, we would not have forward slash, otherwise we can change our constraints based on other possible inputs/scenarios.

Comment: What you are doing could be achieved in another way: `\/ +([^\/]*)$`

Comment: This assumes there will be no forward slashes in the target content (not confirmed by OP). Also, a small note: You don’t need to escape forward slashes, ie this is the same regex: `.+/\s+(.+)`. If your language (eg JS, but not java for example) requires you to escape it because the forward slash is part of your language, then sure, show it in situ.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This is a pythonish answer (my mistake).  I'll leave this for it's value as it could apply many languages**

Another approach is to split it and then rejoin it.

```
data = 'BURGERDAY / PPA / This is a burger fest'
```

Here it is in four steps:

```
parts = data.split('/')   # break into a list by '/'
parts = parts[2:]         # get a new list excluding the first 2 elements
output = '/'.join(parts)  # join them back together with a '/'
output = output.strip()   # strip spaces from each side of the output
```

And in one concise line:

```
output= str.join('/', data.split('/')[2:]).strip()
```

Note: I feel that `str.join(..., ...)` is more readable than '...'.join(...) in some contexts.  It is the identical call though.